Same package shows 2 different names on terminal and on GNOME's menu
I have recently installed alacarte from the terminal; when I run apt list --installed on the terminal it shows the name is alacarte, but on GNOME's menu it's shown as "Main menu".
I have faced this problem multiple times.
My question is:

Why does it show different names on the terminal and on GNOME's menu?
How do I find out the package's original name if I want to uninstall it?




The name shown in the launcher is the value of the Name[<language_prefix>]=<value> key / value pair listed in the application's .desktop file in /usr/share/applications.
The application's .desktop file in /usr/share/applications is provided by the package that installed it.
The package that provides a certain file can be identified by passing the file's path to dpkg -S.
So, putting everything toghether, to print the name of the package that installed an application starting from the name shown in the launcher, run:
grep -l '^Name\[[^]]\+\]=<application_localized_name>$' /usr/share/applications/* | xargs dpkg -S | cut -d: -f1

replacing <application_localized_name> with the application's localized name (which is the name shown in the launcher). For example, on my system that would be Menù principale:
% grep -l '^Name\[[^]]\+\]=Menù principale$' /usr/share/applications/* | xargs dpkg -S | cut -d: -f1
alacarte


I can't exclude there could be an edge case where an application's localized name could match a completely different application's name (either localized in the same language or localized in another language), leading to multiple package names being printed.
So, to be a bit stricter, you could run:
grep -l '^Name\[<language_prefix>\]=<application_localized_name>$' /usr/share/applications/* | xargs dpkg -S | cut -d: -f1

replacing <language_prefix> with your language's prefix and <application_localized_name> with the application's localized name (which is the name shown in the launcher). For example, on my system those would be it and Menù principale:
% grep -l '^Name\[it\]=Menù principale$' /usr/share/applications/* | xargs dpkg -S | cut -d: -f1
alacarte

But if an application's localized name happens to match a completely different application's name localized in the same language, you'll have to make an educated guess inspecting the descriptions of the packages.
grep -l '^Name\[<language_prefix>\]=<application_localized_name>$' /usr/share/applications/* | xargs dpkg -S | cut -d: -f1 | xargs dpkg -s

% grep -l '^Name\[it\]=Menù principale$' /usr/share/applications/* | xargs dpkg -S | cut -d: -f1 | xargs dpkg -s
Package: alacarte
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Installed-Size: 312
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 3.52.0-1
Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0, gir1.2-glib-2.0, gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 (>= 3.5.3), gir1.2-gtk-3.0, gnome-menus (>= 3.5.3), python3-cairo, python3-gi, python3:any
Description: easy GNOME menu editing tool
 Alacarte is an easy-to-use menu editor for GNOME that can add
 and edit new entries and menus. It works with the freedesktop.org
 menu specification and should work with any desktop environment
 that uses the spec.
Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers <pkg-gnome-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Homepage: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/alacarte


Packages frequently include multiple actual programs inside the package with multiple names.  Also, frequently the package name and the primary program name may be the same but capitalized, punctuated, and spelled differently.  Sometimes you even get multiple executables from different packages with the same or very similar names.  (This is what the alternatives system is good at fixing.)
You can find the name of the package that supplies a file with dpkg -S filename... (assuming it came from a package) and you can get the list of files in a package with dpkg -L packagename
